# Simple in-memory PowerShell Provider?

Tags: powershell

I want a PSDrive that wraps a simple Dictionary (or PSObject) so that I can do non-persistent operations like this:

```
New-PSDrive xx Dictionary ""
"Powershell" >xx:name
"Hello $xx:name"
```

Above updated to illustrate using drive like a variable namespace.

Obviously the Variable provider is close, but it seems to include global variables etc, while I something more akin to a namespace: empty until populated

I've recently learned of the [SHiPS](https://github.com/PowerShell/SHiPS) provider, which seems fantastic for more complex situations, but so far my attempts to use SHiPS to simulate the above have been unsuccessful.

Is there an existing PSCmdletProvider which can do this?

Comment: Obviously the Variable provider is close, but it seems to include global variables etc, while I something more akin to a namespace: empty until populated

Comment: It sounds like non-persistent data storage is what you're after, predominantly. Is there any reason, that you know of, that you couldn't use Docker containers for this purpose? If you run a container with the `--rm` parameter, the container will simply die off after its entrypoint terminates. `docker run --rm --interactive --tty microsoft/powershell` Is there something else you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I hadn't even considered docker.   It seems rather heavyweight compared to an in-memory provider.

Comment: @Burt_Harris is there a reason you need this type of interface specifically and can't just directly use a `Dictionary` object? A PSProvider is rather heavy (in terms of implementation) which is why SHiPS was created in the first place.