# In Powershell is it possible to publish module to an in-memory storage?

Tags: powershell, module

**Motivation**

I need to test my custom module loading logic. Publishing a test module for real and then installing it for real is just too time consuming in Powershell.

So, instead of publishing a test module to a real directory I was wondering if there is some kind of in-memory provider that can satisfy the Powershell module functions, like `Publish/Install/Import-Module`.

**EDIT 1**

Basically, I want the same thing as [Simple in-memory PowerShell Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045923/simple-in-memory-powershell-provider)

**EDIT 2**

I specifically need the following functions to work with the in-memory storage:

1. `Install-Module`
2. `Find-Module`
3. `Get-Module` with or without `-ListAvailable`
4. `Import-Module`

Importing a psm1 file does not cut it. Creating a module with `New-Module` does not cut it either.

Comment: `New-Module` takes a script block and instantly provides those functions & members to the current session: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module?view=powershell-6

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify the need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`Import-Module "Path to your psm1 file"`

for testing purpose when it is in under development.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously just had *test* modules setup with a PSD1 and PSM1 file and then dropped the PS1 file into the directory when it is ready for testing. As long as you have the export functions section of the PDS1 set to * it should load your PS1 file when you import the module.

The other way would be to simply save your function as a PS1 file and then Dot Source it. For example:

```
. C:\Temp\TestFunction.ps1
```

Note the period then the space. This will load the function into memory and will be gone after you restart the session.

Comment: I am failing to grasp the relevance of this answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this entirely in memory but you can use a directory. Possibly you might be able to create a ramdisk or similar, but a regular directory on an SSD should be quick enough for most purposes. Run

```
# register the repo
Register-PSRepository -Name MyRepo -SourceLocaton c:\mydirectory

# publish to it
Publish-Module -Name MyModule -Repository MyRepo

# install from it
Install-Module -Name MyModule -Repoitory MyRepo
```